# Getting information from different tables [Best Practice]

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a MySQL database that I have to get information from, said information is spread across different tables and I have been Googling for a while for the best method to get this information and found quite some information, but I was wondering if there is a best practice that I should try, since the tables may get quite big later on I would like to have a good start regarding functionality, and speed.

Comment: Are those tables related through foreign keys?

Comment: as far as I can tell they're not (I tried reverse-engineering the tables to get the ER diagram but no relationships came out of it).

Comment: If the tables are alreay designed, you are a little late for having a good start ;) Could you make an example we could look at?

Comment: I know I'm late in that aspect haha. What would be a good example? The Table structure?

Comment: Yes, because without foreign keys, how do you know which information to get from different tables?

Comment: basically they just told me "we'd like a table (html) that contains these info from our tables"

Comment: @Luis Armando do you know the JOIN syntax, its hard to tell?

Comment: Provided you need this data (from multiple tables) together, I would suggest creating stored routines in MySQL and then executing only 1 SQL statement from PHP.  Inside the stored function you can query multiple tables, collect all required data, then return the full dataset to the calling PHP program.  This way you have a minimal db connection overhead (1 call) and all your database logic is inside one function.  We have a large website (around 1000 different pages) all designed in this way.

Comment: wow 1000 pages.. how do you cope ;P

Comment: I thought Stored Procedures were only for SQL, in MySQL where are they placed? I mean, where should I create them? (I already googled some info as to how to use them and get the information out of them, just nothing on where to create them)

Comment: @Lawrence yeah I know it, but I had completely forgotten about its existence

Answer (score 0):

If your records in your database are related through ID's or primary keys, you can use the `JOIN` syntax to get data from multiple tables through 1 query.

Example :

- Table `car : id, brand`
- Table `driver : id, name, car_id`

You can get all the drivers of a car in 1 query:

```
SELECT * FROM driver LEFT JOIN car ON (car.id = driver.car_id) WHERE car.id=5;
```

This is just a basic example, but read the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (or tutorials) to go on.